# writing code in eclipse for Robot Framework under selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

How can I perform click action on below link in robot framework?

```
<a href="JavaScript:;">COMMON MASTERS</a>
```

[image]

Xpath: `//*[@id="theMenu"]/li[1]/h3/div/a`

**I already tried normal Xpath technique**
code:
Set Focus To Element Xpath:
`//*[@id="theMenu"]/li[1]/h3/div/a`
Click Element
xpath: `//*[@id="theMenu"]/li[1]/h3/div/a`

Result:

> 'Xpath: //*[@id="theMenu"]/li[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OVEn.png)/h3/div/a' not found.

**I already tried JavaScript technique**

Execute JavaScript

```
document. Evaluate("//*[@id='theMenu']/li[1]/h3/div/a", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.Click();
```

it should be click but it's doing nothing.

Comment: Probably your webelement is inside frame/iframe. I see frame#leftContant on the screenshot. Try to execute `Select frame  leftContant` before clicking the element.  [SeleniumLibrary](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20Frame)

Comment: BTW!  Pay attention that there should not be space after `xpath:` e.g. should be `XPATH://...` or `XPATH://...` but not `XPATH: //...`

Comment: @Sam Maksymyshyn      Now it's working. Thanks for the support